# "adjustPan" is not working well

Tags: android, keyboard, adjustpan

I'm creating android chat application.
However, when keyboard is opened, it little covers the EditText.
If I use "adjustResize" it dose not cover the EditText but it covers ListView.

Manifest:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lV_chat"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarChat"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/space_6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space_6dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_text_input_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/eT_chat"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/transparency"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space_20dp"    
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_send_button_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/iB_send"
            android:background="@color/light_blue"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: keyboard is closed]

[image: keyboard is opened]

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lV_chat"
            android:divider="@null"
             />



    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/eT_chat"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/iB_send"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

you can have `android:layout_marginBottom="your edittext's layout's width"` to your `main layout` which contains `listview` and then it should fix your issue using `Relative layout` and inside that `Linear layout`.

and remember dont add these lines to your `linear layout`

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

Relative layout should have `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` which contains `EditText` and send `icon`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion "adjustResize" is your best bet .This will resize the list view to accommodate the keyboard. You can use bottomPadding in the list.
"adjustPan" will not be of much help as it will shift the entire layout and it will not look good.

Comment: Did you adjustResize?adjustResize will resize the list not scroll it

Comment: I'm sorry. My expression is not appropriate.

Comment: If I use adjustResize, all layout moves up with keyboard opened. But in my app dose not. I don't the reasons for this.